# How to arrange the objects in a specific manner in array?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, object

I have a typescript file & an array of objects and the keys are in sorted manner. But i wants the order of keys in a specific manner. The object is coming from the database and keys inside every object are in sorted manner.

Comment: for example original array is something like which is coming from database
Array = [
{
class = "",
date = "",
id = "",
level = "", 
name = "", 
parent = "",
value = "",
unique = ""
},
{
class = "",
date = "",
id = "",
level = "", 
name = "", 
parent = "",
value = "",
unique = ""
},
and so on
]   

and the expected array should be 
array = [
{
date = "",
class = "",
name = "",
parent = "",
value = "",
id = "",
unique = "" 
},
and so on 
]

Comment: Properties in JavaScript are *mostly* in insertion order, see [details here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order). You need to tweak whatever creates those objects to make sure they are created as you wish.

Comment: But the data is coming from the database. in key sorted manner.

Comment: *How* is it coming from the DB? What turns it into JS objects? Some code has to be responsible for that. Check what that code does. You can't send "JavaScript objects" over network connections, they have to be serialized in *some way* (often JSON). And then *something* needs to take that serialized form and turn it into JS objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can just remap it to another array and change the order of the keys

Assuming you have an array of objects `dbResults` coming from the database and the initial order of keys is: class, date, id, level, name, parent, value, unique

```
dbResultsRemapped = dbResults.map((row) => ({
    date: row.date,
    class: row.class,
    name: row.name,
    parent: row.parent,
    value: row.value,
    id: row.id,
    unique: row.unique,
    level: row.level,
}))
```

The remap above will change the order of the keys to: date, class, name, parent, value, id, unique, level